# JQuery sortable wont work when img is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I know this issue might have been raised before but I still could not find the answer after long time searching..

I am trying to use jQuery sortable function to make my images swappable. The function works fine when the position of the img is not set. But when the position is set ( I want to fixed the images at some particular point on the viewpoint) the swap won't happen at all.

Is there a way to make sortable work while the position is set to either "absolute" or "fix?"

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable > div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="sortable">
  <div id="demo5" , class="card" , draggable="true" , style="
      top: 135px;
      left: 190px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: move;
      float:left;
      visibility: show;">
    Card 1
  </div>


  <div id="demo6" , class="card" , draggable="true" , style="
      top: 135px;
      left: 245px;
      position:fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      cursor: move;
      visibility: show;">
    Card 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I amended the positions of the cards slightly so they are visible in the Snippet. Also, just FYI, your HTML has commas in between the attributes which are invalid. You should also look in to putting the styles in an external stylesheet instead of bloating the HTML. Finally, doesn't explicitly setting the position of an element make the entire point of `sortable()` completely redundant?

Comment: Remove commas please.

Comment: I just want to make img swappable while fixing them in a specific position in the screen. I am not too sure how to make both work..

Comment: `sortable` changes the position of elements in the DOM, AFAIK - but DOM order of course has no effect on fixed positioned elements. So you would need to re-calculate all positions … Do you really need to position the individual images? Would it not perhaps be enough if their container was fixed …? (And btw., float of course has no effect on fixed positioned elements either.)